# Tibco Jaspersoft Studio - Java beans datasource from database

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I would like to test the Jaspersoft java beans datasource, but all the references I found contains just static datas.
I need to use a database as a source of the java beans datas.

Code example:
public class OrderFactory {

```
public static Collection<Order> getOrders() {
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    orders.add(new Order(new String("first"), new String("first")));

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@X.X.X.X:1521:jd92";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"xx","yy");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select sddoco, sdlitm from f4211");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            orders.add(new Order(rs.getString("SDDOCO"), rs.getString("sdlitm")));              
            orders.add(new Order(new String("1"), new String("apples")));
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 



    return orders;
}
```

So it adds the (first, first) as in the examples, but do not add anything in the while loop (just like it has a problem with the connection).

The example code works fine when run in native java.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks strange that you are using JavaBeans based datasource in this case. You can add tracing information with help of logger. Maybe you have a wrong data adapter or wrong template

Comment: I did it because I want to strongly preprocess the data coming from the database before I format it with Jasper.
What other usage the JavaBeans has?
How can I add tracking information?
Unfortunatelly I got no error messages at all, and I can't see the console log in Jasper inspite of that I turnet on Java console in it.

Comment: I managed to get the console messages:

(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) invoke0(..) : Got an exception! 
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) invoke0(..) : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: I am also stuck in this exact point. Any resolution will be really helpful. The JDBC code executes when in restart Jasper Studio but after the initial first successful run, I always get "No suitable driver found" exception.